# how to hide selection on UITableview?

Tags: iphone

i want to disable click on particular Cell.it means, **i want not to show highlight color(selection indication) when we touch on particular cell?** any help please?

Answer (score 15):

Either use `cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;` or return `false` or return `null` in the delegate method [tableView:willSelectRowAtIndexPath](http://developer.apple.com/IPhone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView:willSelectRowAtIndexPath:).

Comment: I set the style to none in the storyboard but my separator lines went berserk. Apparently that was due to not reading the documentation, returning nil in the specified delegate method solved the problem... thanks for saving me some time.

Comment: what if I need to define a custom selection? So I need hide the default selection, NOT disable the selection at all

Answer (score 2):

**Swift**:

> If you're using a custom cell:

```
class YourCustomCell: UITableViewCell {
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        setup()
    }

    init() {
        setup()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    fileprivate func setup() {
        self.selectionStyle = .none
    }
}
```

> If you're not using a custom cell:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CellIdentifierID")
    cell.selectionStyle = .none
    return cell
}
```

**Bonus**: If you want to hide the cell selection and also don't want to call `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {...}` then only set `cell.isUserInteractionEnabled = false`. However, this is not a good practice.